# PHP Ajax disable / enable submit button

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I'm using this sample code :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp
to do a live name search and display if it's available or not.

How do I disable the forms submit button if the name is in use, but enable it if the name is available ?

Many Thanks :)

Thanks for the advise. I've added this to the function and now the button disables when I type anything in..

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
```

How do I do this just for a match ?
Thanks

Comment: Problem is I don't know what to try. I was planning on adding an if else to the checking page, so if there is a match disable the button.

Comment: Am I right that you already use jQuery for disabling the button, but not for Ajax? Using jQuery is way easier than doing it by hand.

Comment: The button is normally active, but I do have jquery loaded for other functionality. using the code @Zulakis posted I do get it disable/enable.  Just need to get if responsetext contains not equals working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to check if the name matches or not and then disable or enable like this:

```
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (xmlhttp.responseText == "available") {
            document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. That works.. but can we do if responsetext contains not equals ?

Comment: Sure. `if (xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf("available") != -1) { ... }`

Comment: I changed to this, but now it doesn't work !
`if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
if (xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf("available") != -1) {
            document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
        }
    }`

Comment: If the page returns a string which contains "available", it enabled the button, if not then it disables it. Change "available" to your needs.

Comment: what is actually returned is a string containing the name and formatting. 
This does contain available, but does seem to like it. I've changed the word to the color code being used and now it seems to be working !

Answer (score 0):

Add disabled="disabled" to the submit button when a name is returned in the callback.

$('#submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: You should mention to use jQuery or prototype, or any other javascript library that uses fizzle ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="id_name"type="text" name="name" onKeyup="testName();"/>
<script>
function testName() {
 $.ajax({
  var data = $('#id_name').val();
  url:'test.php',
  success: function(data){
   if(/*name in use*/) {$('#submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');}
   else {$('#submit-button').removeAttr("disabled");}
  }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can use testName() onfocus event also